# How to: Implement Programatic Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, constraints

I am working on learning programmatic UI via Swift UI... Everything is fun so far I recommend anyone "afraid" of Swift UI should jump right in. Is anyone able to correctly constrain the code below? It only fits correctly in the Swift UI generated preview which was an iPhone 8 device. Any suggestions would be appreciated I have tried `.aspectRatio` to start but no good progress has been made yet.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    
                    //Header
                    StrokeText(text: "App Name", width: 0.5, color: .black)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 45, weight: .bold))
                        .position(x: 188, y: 35)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity,
                               alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color.init(hue: 0.2722, saturation: 0.89, brightness: 0.29, opacity: 1.0)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        
                    //Data View
                    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        
                        
                        Color.init(red: 0.33, green: 0.56, blue: 0.27)
                            .position(x: 188, y: -114)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        
                        
                        //Todays List
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            
                            Button(action: {}){
                                Text(" Today's List    ")
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(Font.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 21.0))
                                    .padding(18)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .background(Color.green)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .position(x: 85, y: 80)
                            }
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
                        }
                        
                        //Tomorrows List
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            Button(action: {}){
                                Text("Tomorrow's List ")
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(Font.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 21.0))
                                    .padding(18)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .background(Color.green)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .position(x: 285, y: 80)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        //This Month
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            Button(action: {}){
                                Text("  This Month   ")
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(Font.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 22.0))
                                    .padding(18)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .background(Color.green)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .position(x: 85, y: 148)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        //Next Month
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            
                            Button(action: {}){
                                Text("    Next Month    ")
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(Font.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 22.0))
                                    .padding(18)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .background(Color.green)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .position(x: 289, y: 148)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        //3% Yeild Or Higher
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            Button(action: {}){
                                Text(" 3% Yield or More")
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(Font.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 17.6))
                                    .padding(18)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .background(Color.green)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .position(x: 85, y: 215)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        //5% Yield Or Higher
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            
                            Button(action: {}){
                                Text("   5% Yield or More ")
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(Font.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 17.0))
                                    .padding(18)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .background(Color.green)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .position(x: 282, y: 215)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        //App Help
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            Button(action: {}){
                                Text("     App Help    ")
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(Font.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 22.0))
                                    .padding(18)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .background(Color.yellow)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .position(x: 83, y: 283)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        //More Apps
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            Button(action: {moreApps()}){
                                Text("    More Apps    ")
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(Font.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 22.0))
                                    .padding(18)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .background(Color.red)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .position(x: 285, y: 283)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        

                        
                      
                        
                    }
                    

                    
                    
                }
                
               
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct StrokeText: View {
    let text: String
    let width: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ZStack{
                Text(text).offset(x:  width, y:  width)
                Text(text).offset(x: -width, y: -width)
                Text(text).offset(x: -width, y:  width)
                Text(text).offset(x:  width, y: -width)
                
            }
            .foregroundColor(color)
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't use constraints in SwiftUI.  You also shouldn't use hard-coded widths & heights as you have done.  Normally you will just describe your layout and let SwiftUI lay it out.  You can use minimum, maximum and recommended width/height in your frames if you want to provide more guidance to SwiftUI layout.  You can also use `GeometryReader` if you want to get the current device dimensions and work from that.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you! I updated my view and improved it a bit